# create custom BCS connector

Tags: bcs, custom-bcs

What are the steps to create a custom bcs connector?

I have a ftp location where the data gets updated every week.

So I want to write a bcs connector which will connect to data source with the location.

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee661740.aspx

Comment: thanks..I know about bcs,external list etc.Need to know regarding custom connector.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff953161(v=office.14).aspx

Have you gone through this msdn link?